# Customization of the theme of several GWT modules

Tags: css, gwt, customization, smartgwt, skin

I have several modules with smartGWT using the same visual theme. Have I to create my own CSS-file and there overwrite necessary classes? If I plug this file to the host-pages of the modules, will my styles always override the standard themes classes?

Comment: Now I simply connect my CSS-file on the host-page of the module at the end of the block head after connection of all the scripts, and it works. I want to be sure that it will always work, because if asynchronous loading of resources will be, my styles can be loaded before the native theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to override somme native style in my css file, the only care I take is to add !important to force my style whatever style is apply by the framework
For exemple:

```
.formTitle,.formTitleFocused,.formTitleDisabled {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
font-size: 11px !important;
color: black !important;
```

}

```
.splitbar:hover  {
cursor: e-resize !important;
```

}

Hope it could help..

Comment: While this approach works, it is bad practice to override styles when you are capable of replacing the initial style altogether.

Comment: I used this method, but  it is really bad practice

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to theme/skin SmartGWT is [described here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html).

Comment: I read the documentation, but there specifically about it does not say about my problem

Comment: You're going to have to do some extrapolation here. You definitely are skinning the application, you're just not calling it skinning. You're calling it modifying the styles. Regardless of the wording, you need to be doing what is described in the docs if you want to modify the look and feel of SmartGWT.

Comment: As I said above, I just override themes styles & it works. I left it without changes